How can I see the javascript console in an Amazon Silk browser running on an Amazon Fire Tablet?
I saw this, but it looks scary: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/webapp-debug-app.html
It's an Android-based browser.  Is there any magic screen taps, setting changes or anything to just see the javascript console?  It's a fairly straightforward single-page app that appears to be working perfectly, but we have an MQTT ping going on in the background that only shows up in the console at debug/verbose level.

Perhaps this answer might help you (got it from a quick google search).
